# How can I capture FreeBSD boot messages displayed on active console?

Tags: console, freebsd

I am working with a developer of NAS4Free (FreeBSD based), and to help diagnose issues, I'm trying to capture the console output generated while booting.

After much searching, I can't find any hints of how to do this.  I found that when toggled into scroll mode with <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd>, I can scroll back up, but what I really want to do is take the whole buffer and dump it to a file that I could then post to Pastebin or similar, so he can go through it and find the possibly problematic areas.

Background:  NAS4Free is running "embedded" on bare metal, so reconfiguring it to dump boot messages to somewhere else isn't possible.

`dmesg` has been used, but doesn't list all the specific entries printed during the boot sequence.

`sysctl -a` has been recommended, and while some of the output is helpful, it still doesn't include all the boot messages.

`/var/log/messages` does not exist, which could mean the logger isn't started (likely to reduce rewrites to the boot media)

========

Basically, I just want a way to just grab the contents of the console's buffer and dump it to a text file on disk, instead of having to manually type out everything that might be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much discussion with the NAS4Free developers, it appears that the information I'm looking for is included in the log `/var/log/system.log`.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `/var/log/messages`.

If you need to extract more info, read the man page of `logger`. With `logger` you can use `syslog` to save the output of the programs.

Comment: `$ cat /var/log/messages
cat: /var/log/messages: No such file or directory`
Looks like it isn't logging all the messages that display during boot.

Comment: Probably your system is not saving the logs or the location of the logs is different to the traditional place. Read http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syslog.conf&apropos=0&sektion=5&manpath=FreeBSD+9.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html .

Comment: I'll try to get in contact with an active developer of NAS4Free and see if that is the case.  On the other hand, I know the text is in a buffer somewhere, because on the physically attached console, I can scroll back to the beginning of boot, I just don't know how to access that buffer.

Comment: @killermist don't edit my post for add the solution. Just add other answer and accept your answer :)